# Banner ads and Interstitial ads not working together

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show a banner ad in a fragment and an Interstitial ad when a user tries to open other activity.

Banner ad and Interstitial ads are working perfectly when I show anyone of that only(i.e. Banner ad is shown when no code is written for Interstitial ad and vice-versa).

When the code for both ads are written the following message is shown in logcat.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
```

The problem with `play-services` seems to be strange because each of the ads load independently as I mentioned above.

Below is my entire fragment code.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);


    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    requestNewInterstitial();
    return root;
}

public void showJoke(final String joke) {

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        launchActivity(joke);
    }


    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            launchActivity(joke);
        }
    });
}

public void launchActivity(String joke){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), JokeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("joke", joke);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

}
```

Please help and  share your views on what could be the issue.

Comment: did you add Google play service in your project?

Comment: Yes it is added. and ads work perfectly independently.

Comment: Remove re-initialization of AdRequest in requestNewInterstitial() method.. Use already created AdRequest object..

Comment: Tried. Not working

Comment: check my code.. its working fine.. http://paste.ofcode.org/PvhjFJs2ddqH3L3rfmPb8p